# Не работает INSERT INTO, в чем может быть причина

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Не работает INSERT INTO, в чем может быть причина? Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

```
<?
function add_to_cart($id)
  {
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
function update_cart()
 {
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty)
    {
        if($_POST[$id] == '0')
        {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $_POST[$id];
        }
    }
 }
function total_items($cart)
  {
    $num_items = 0;        
    if(is_array($cart))
    {
        foreach($cart as $id => $qty)
        {
            $num_items += $qty;
        }
    }
    return $num_items;           
  }
function total_price($cart)
{
    $total_price = 0.0;
    db_connect();
    if(is_array($cart))
    {
        foreach($cart as $id => $qty)
        {
            $query = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE id='$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if($result)
            {
                $item_price = mysql_result($result,0,'price');
                $total_price += $item_price * $qty;
            }
        }
    } 
    return $total_price;           
} ?>
```

---

```
   <? foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity):
     $product = get_product($id);
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td align="center"><?=$product['title'];?></td>
      <td align="center"><?=number_format($product['price'],2);?> руб.</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" name="<?=$id;?>" maxlength="2" value="<?=$quantity;?>" /></td>
      <td align="center"><?=number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2);?> руб.</td>
  </tr>      
 <? endforeach;?>
```

---

```
<?
      }
         if($_SESSION['cart'] && isset($_POST['order']))
            {
             $name = $_POST['name'];
         $s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
         $address = $_POST['address'];
    $post_index = $_POST['post_index'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');    
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity):
    $product = get_product($id);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders(name,s_name,address,post_index,email,date,time,product,prod_id,price,qty) VALUES ('$name','$s_name','$address','$post_index','$email','$date','$time','{$product['title']}','{$product['id']}','{$product['price']}','$quantity')");
    endforeach;    
    echo "<p align='center'>Ваш заказ успешно принят! Спасибо за покупку!</p>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: сделайте пожалуйста дамп получившегося SQL после подставления переменных

на всякий пожарный заэкранируйте поля date и time бэктиками т.к. эти слова используются самой базой данных

проверьте сами или скиньте сюда сам код таблицы, какими типами представлены поля (возможно дата или время не в том формате или еще чего)

p.s. Совет - операции с БД переделать на PDO с байндингом переменных или как минимум добавить фильтрацию данных приходящих из POST, т.к. в вашем случае они напрямую идут в базу данных, что не есть хорошо

Comment: @zippp, благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
 WHERE id='$id'"
```

и везде-везде ниже выделяем имена переменных, добавляемых к запросу, точками (конкатенация), вот так:

```
 WHERE id='".$id."'"
```

Comment: @deivan, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

используй такой же синтаксис при инсерте, что и при апдейте

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `orders` SET title='".$title."',description='".$description."', price='".$price."',image='".$image."',cat='".$cat."'");
```

только поля на свои поменяй

Comment: @mountpoint, поменяла, изменений нет

Comment: @Kokos, а зачем вы там foreach используете? у вас должен добавляться один заказ, а не несколько, насколько я понимаю

Comment: @mountpoint, для того чтобы пройтись по массиву cart, выбрать товары которые есть в корзине и поместить это все в базу. Редактировала код

Comment: @Kokos, у вас неправильно структура базы сделана. нужно создавать как минимум 2 таблицы для заказов - orders и product_orders

Comment: @mountpoint, благодарю за помощь